# How Can I Create SHA512 Hash In Node Js ... How Can i convert this java code into NodeJs

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, hash, cryptojs

How can i convert this java into NodeJS

```
byte[] decodedKey = Hex.decodeHesecretKey.toCharArray());    
SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(decodedKey, algorithm);    
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(algorithm);    
mac.init(keySpec);    
byte[] dataBytes = data.getBytes("UTF-8");    
byte[] signatureBytes = mac.doFinal(dataBytes);    
String signature = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(signatureBytes),"UTF-8"); 
return signature;
```

Comment: This npm module will do the trick for you. https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-sha512. Does that help?

Comment: Shenoy Sir..It Is working Good.. But Output is different comparing with Java Output